# RectF.intersects acting strangely

Tags: java, android, collision-detection

I have been using android's `RectF` in my game to detect collisions on movement. When an entity moves, it gets the object in the world at the position it would like to move. If this object is an instance of a `RectF` or my `Entity` class, the entity is told it cannot move there. Here is the code for my map checking method:

```
public Object getCollisionObject(Entity ent){
    for(Entity e : entities){
        if(e == ent)continue;
        if(e.collides(ent.getBoundsF())return e;
    }
    for(RectF r : collisions){
        if(ent.collides(r))return r;
    }
    return null;
}

public void moveHere(Entity e, float x, float y){
    float originalX = e.getX();
    float originalY = e.getY();
    e.setX(x);
    e.setY(y);
    Object o = getCollisionObject(e):
    boolean moved = true;
    if(o instanceof RectF || o instanceof Entity)moved = false;
    e.setX(originalX);//actual movement is done in the entity class if this method returns true
    e.setY(originalY);
    return moved;
}
```

Here are the relevant methods in the `Entity` class:

```
public RectF getBoundsF(){
    return new RectF(x, y, x + width, y + height);
}

public boolean collides(RectF rect){
    return RectF.intersects(getBoundsF(), rect);
}
```

Here is a quick video to demonstrate my problem (the red boxes are drawn around collisions and the blue ones are drawn around bitmap bounds):

[VidMe Link](https://vid.me/fFxj)

From the video, it seems that on the bottom and right walls, the entity cannot move closer than its width (32 pixels) to the wall. However, on the left and top walls, the entity is able to successfully move as close as possible. The same problem happens on the left and top **sides** of the walls (on every wall). I am very confused and have spent hours trying to solve this but to no avail. If any more information is required, please do ask in the comments.

Comment: You shouldn't need a video to show the problem. Just provide a concrete example (in terms of positions of the entity and the rectangle) where `intersects` doesn't behave as you expect it to.

Comment: I thought a visual demonstration would aid in providing a better understanding of the problem. I'm not great at explaining in words... @JonSkeet

Comment: So explain it in code - all you need to do is provide an example, in code, of where `intersects` doesn't give the expected result. That only needs to be about 5 lines of code. Add logging to your app so that you can see the relevant values at the times it's behaving unexpectedly, and the rest should be simple.